# View.gettag returning null, what have I missed in ListView/ArrayAdapter setup?

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

I have a custom class "Something" which holds some ints and strings.  I'm making a page to allow the user to see each current Something's description, and a button to edit or delete next to each one.

I have overridden toString() in the Something class, so that it can return a description to be put into the TextView field.

list_task_edit.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".EditTaskList">
    ...
    <ListView 
android:id="@+id/edit_task_listview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ListView>

    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

edit_task_list_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/edit_task_name"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/edit_task_edit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_edittask"
    android:onClick=""
    />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/edit_task_delete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_delete_task"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="deleteTask"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

(I haven't put a method for editTask yet, as I'm not up to there)

```
public class EditTaskList extends Activity {

private static ArrayList<Something> list;

ArrayAdapter<Something> arrayAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_task_edit);
    list = MainActivity.getMasterList();

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Something>
    (this,
            R.layout.edit_task_list_item,
            R.id.edit_task_name,
            list);
    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.edit_task_listview);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}

public void deleteTask(View view){
    Something thisItem = (Something)view.getTag();
    if(thisItem == null){
        System.out.println("Bad things");
    }
    arrayAdapter.remove(thisItem);
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
    ...
}
```

My diagnostic line to check if thisItem == null is going off every time.  What am I missing?  Am I declaring the ArrayAdapter wrong somehow?

Comment: I do not see where you are even setting the tag? Are you expecting the native array adapter to do this for you?

Comment: Yes, I thought the ArrayAdapter did that.  I guess not.  Do I have to implement a Holder to set the tag?

Comment: How are you calling delete task?

Comment: android:onclick on the button associated with that line, as you can see in one of the xlm files above.

Comment: So, clearly I have no idea what I'm doing here.  I'm having trouble finding a tutorial that covers everything I need, but doesn't also cover a hundred things I don't need.  And I am having a lot of trouble working out what I do and don't need.

I've now created a custom adapter with a viewholder, but I don't know if that's enough or too much, or how to plug everything together.

Comment: No worries, I've had the same problems myself. I added an answer, let me know if it helps and if you need more direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your deleteTask event will not return your list item, instead it will return a button view.

To get the functionality which you want, you should build a custom adapter to keep track of your list items. To do this, you will need to extend the BaseAdapter.

See this response for more detail:

[How to add/remove item from listview in android when click button in item listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412341/how-to-add-remove-item-from-listview-in-android-when-click-button-in-item-listvi)

The key point is that in the GetView method, you are able to set a tag on your list button which denotes the position of the container item. This then will let you delete the item specified by that position in the OnClickListener for the button.

Comment: What's the difference between a BaseAdapter and an ArrayAdapter?  Will a base adapter work with my array of Somethings?

Comment: BaseAdapter is just the parent class of ArrayAdapter, so it should work. You should also be able to use an ArrayAdapter however if you like.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help.  I don't have enough rep to upvote this answer.

Answer (score 4):

Updated, working code.  In case it's useful to others:

```
public class EditTaskList extends Activity {

    private static ArrayList<Something> list;
private CustomAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_task_edit);
        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.edit_task_listview);
        list = MainActivity.getMasterList();
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void resetAdapter(){
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.edit_task_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Something>{
        private ArrayList<Something> things;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        class ViewHolder {
            public TextView text;
            public Button editButton;
            public Button deleteButton;
        }

        public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Something> things) {
            super(context, R.layout.edit_task_list_item, things);
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.things = things;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            // reuse views
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_task_list_item, null);
                // configure view holder
                viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edit_task_name);
                viewHolder.editButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edit_task_edit);
                viewHolder.deleteButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edit_task_delete);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }

            else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            viewHolder.text.setTag(position);
            viewHolder.text.setText(things.get(position).toString());
            viewHolder.deleteButton.setTag(position);
            viewHolder.editButton.setTag(position); //currently does nothing

            viewHolder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                int tag = (Integer)view.getTag();
                things.remove(tag);
                resetAdapter();
                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```