# Add/Remove Item in activity on listview's item click

Tags: android, listview

I have searched a lot in SO, but didn't get similar type thread. In my application, i need to add or remove item  in activity's layout when user clicks on listview's item. Listview displays data using a custom array adapter. If user clicks on an item then it will be added to the activity's layout and further clicks on the same item, it will be removed. I don't know how to accomplish this task. Any help will be appreciated in this context.

Here is an image:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add/remove item from listview in android when click button in item listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412341/how-to-add-remove-item-from-listview-in-android-when-click-button-in-item-listvi)

Comment: Perform Add/Remove Operation in `ArrayList` and update adapter with `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: @Hamstersztyk I think, you have misunderstood my question.

Comment: so you should describe your problem more clearly, because now it seems  duplicate

Comment: @Pragnesh Ghoda, i do not want any changes in listview, i just want to add or remove custom view in activity when user clicks on listview item that it.

Comment: Where to add in Activity and where is your ListView You should explain that clearly.

Comment: What i get you want something like `ChipView` to add/remove tags on list Item click . Right now its too broad cause you did not provide any effort of code . So google it `ChipView` . If this is your problem .

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what UI effect do you want.
1. If you want the top panel section in your image fixed(do not scroll) when scroll list, then you can:

> - Use a `LinearLayout` as root element
> - Add a `LinearLayout` as top panel
> - Add `ListView` below top panel
> - Create a selectedView.xml that you what add to top panel when click a item of `ListView`

When user clicks item of `ListView`, you can try code below:

```
ItemModel itemData = dataList.get(position)
// inflate selectItemView and add to top panel
View selectItemView= LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.selectedView, topPanelView, true);
View text1 = selectItemView.findViewById(xxx);
text1.setText(itemData.getxxx);
...
//inflate other field using itemData
...
```

2. If you want top panel scroll out of top when scroll `ListView`.
   Make top panel as `HeaderView` of `ListView` and follow the part step of 1 and code.